# How to create a redirect for the log in in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

im trying to make the login error from mediawiki (the one that appears when you are not log in asking you to log in), that instead of asking you, it redirect you directly to the log in page, i have added in the MediaWiki:Loginreqpagetext, the following line:

```
 #REDIRECT[http://10.101.3.21/wikitest/index.php?title=Special%3AUserLogin&returnto=Main+Page]
```

but it doesnt automatically redirect, any suggestions?

ps: also tried with #REDIRECT [[Special:Userlogin]] still doesnt automatically redirect

Comment: man answering my own mediawiki questions is getting old, but for anybody interested:

add 

         $this->redirect( SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Userlogin' )->getFullURL( $query ) );

in \include\output page.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the landing page of Mediawiki 1.19.1 to directly go to Special:UserLogin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123554/how-can-i-change-the-landing-page-of-mediawiki-1-19-1-to-directly-go-to-special)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man answering my own mediawiki questions is getting old, but for anybody interested:

add

```
        $this->redirect( SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Userlogin' )->getFullURL( $query ) );
```

in \include\output under:   public function loginToUse() {

Comment: It's probably dependent on your version. The approach you suggested here didn't work for me, and the `loginToUse` method is commented as being deprecated. Instead, this approach worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123554/how-can-i-change-the-landing-page-of-mediawiki-1-19-1-to-directly-go-to-special/11146915#11146915